# Re-populate additional fields on Contact Form on failure of form validation

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm using [additional fields](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/README.md#adding-additional-fields) on my contact form. I want to re-populate the additional fields if/when the form fails validation, but it's not working so far.

To re-populate a **standard** field, the code uses an attribute of message using dot syntax…

```
<input name="fromName" id="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}" type="text">
```

But for **additional fields** the value is stored as an attribute of message.message using [the subscript syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) (the use of square brackets below)…

```
<input name="message[Phone]" id="phone" type="text" value="">
```

I'm having trouble accessing the substring value on message.message. In my specific example, I have several radio buttons that need their selections remembered in case anything goes wrong. Here's what I expected to work…

```
{% for course in courses %}
    <input id={{ course.slug }}" name="message[Course]" type="radio" value="{{ course }}"
         {% if message is defined and message.message[Course] == course %}
             checked="checked"
         {% endif%}>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this code outputs the template error:

```
Variable "Course" does not exist.
```

How can I re-populate the additional fields for the contact form plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the changelog:

> 1.7.0
>
> Added the ability to access individual message fields values via `message.messageFields` when a validation error occurred. For example, the value of the input `message[Phone]` can now be accessed via `message.messageFields['Phone']`.

So I think you should be using `message.messageFields[Course]` rather than `message.message[Course]`